# Identifying the Web element with same class name in Selenium

Tags: selenium, twitter, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I have tried to get the number of tweets(tweet count) through selenium

Here is the page source:

```
  <li class="DashboardProfileCard-stat Arrange-sizeFit">
    <a class="DashboardProfileCard-statLink u-textUserColor u-linkClean u-block"
        title="1 Tweet"
        href="/saisiva14"
        data-element-term="tweet_stats">
      <span class="DashboardProfileCard-statLabel u-block">Tweets</span>
      <span class="DashboardProfileCard-statValue" data-is-compact="false">1</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="DashboardProfileCard-stat Arrange-sizeFit">
      <a class="DashboardProfileCard-statLink u-textUserColor u-linkClean u-block"
          title="38 Following"
          href="/following"
          data-element-term="follower_stats">
        <span class="DashboardProfileCard-statLabel u-block">Following</span>
        <span class="DashboardProfileCard-statValue" data-is-compact="false">38</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="DashboardProfileCard-stat Arrange-sizeFit">
      <a class="DashboardProfileCard-statLink u-textUserColor u-linkClean u-block"
          title="4 Followers"
          href="/followers"
          data-element-term="following_stats">
        <span class="DashboardProfileCard-statLabel u-block">Followers</span>
        <span class="DashboardProfileCard-statValue" data-is-compact="false">4</span>
      </a>
    </li>
```

I could not able to locate the web element for getting Tweets,Followers & following. The reason is span class names are common for all these elements.Please help me .

Answer (score 1):

To get number of Tweets/ Following/ Followers, You can try the below statements:

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@title, 'Tweet')]/span[2]")).getText());
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@title, 'Following')]/span[2]")).getText());
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@title, 'Followers')]/span[2]")).getText());
```

To click on the Tweets/ Following/ Followers links, You can try the below statements:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@title, 'Tweet')]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@title, 'Following')]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@title, 'Followers')]")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[./span[text()='Tweets']]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[./span[text()='Following']]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[./span[text()='Followers']]")).click();
```

The above statements are working fine for me.

Comment: Yeah it's working fine .xpath is the better option .Thanks for your post

Comment: @Sivasailanathan Welcome. If you found solution, accept the answer. So that others also can know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
IList<IWebElement> elements = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("DashboardProfileCard-stat"));
foreach (IWebElement element in elements)
   {
     IWebElement ele = element.FindElement(By.ClassName("DashboardProfileCard-statLabel"));
     if (ele.Text == "Tweets")
        {
          return element.FindElement(By.ClassName("DashboardProfileCard-statValue")).Text;
        }
   }
```

this is using C#, you can modify accordingly if anyother language is used.

Answer (score 0):

The selector `.DashboardProfileCard-stat span:nth-child(2)` should give you the collection of web elements pointing to the count. For example in Java:

`ArrayList<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".DashboardProfileCard-stat span:nth-child(2)"))`

Then you can use `elements.get(0).getText()` for tweets. `elements.get(1).getText()` for following. `elements.get(2).getText()` for followers. So:

`ArrayList<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".DashboardProfileCard-stat span:nth-child(2)"));
int tweets = elements.get(0).getText();
int following = elements.get(1).getText();
int followers = elements.get(2).getText();`

Of course, do your appropriate safety checks, etc. Check the length of the array before access.

Answer (score 0):

This code is in Java :)

1. capture all the parents of the "SPAN" into a collection item.
2. Iterate on the collection to find the span elements (which are child of `<a>` tag) and capture text based on the class name variation **statLabel** / **statValue**".

   ```
   List<WebElement> webElement = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[@class='DashboardProfileCard-stat Arrange-sizeFit']//a"));

   for (WebElement element : webElement) {
       System.out.println(element.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'statLabel')]")).getText());
       System.out.println(element.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'statValue')]")).getText());
   }
   ```